# Switch the whole style of my app from my custom styles to default materialDesignStyles

Tags: wpf

I am looking for way to swap the whole wpf app style from my custom styles to default materialDesign styles and at runtime if possible.Help would be much needed.Thank you

I tried this but it's not parctical for the whole app .

```
namespace MaterialDesign
{
    public class ButtonConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            
            bool isMaterialDesign = (bool)value;

            if (isMaterialDesign)
            {
                return Application.Current.FindResource("MaterialDesignFlatAccentBgButton");
            }
            else
            {
                return Application.Current.FindResource("CustomButtonStyle");
            }
        }


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

//app.xaml

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Default.xaml" />
```

//Window.xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:GenericConverter x:Key="StyleConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <materialDesign:Card Padding="20" Margin="70" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Welcome" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHeadline6TextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 40 0 0"/>
                <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Username" Margin="0 0 0 8"/>
                <PasswordBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Password" Margin="0 0 0 8" Password=""/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Login" Style="{Binding IsMaterialDesign, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}" Margin="0 0 10 0"/>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Content="Register" Margin="0 10 10 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Don't have an account?" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnStyle}" Margin="0 10"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Register here" TextDecorations="Underline" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
        <ToggleButton
            x:Name="DarkModeToggle"
            Checked="DarkModeToggle_Checked"
            Unchecked="DarkModeToggle_Checked"
      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignSwitchToggleButton}"
      ToolTip="Default ToggleButton Style" Margin="0 300 0 0"/>
    </Grid>
   
</Window> 
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
```

I am looking for a practical solution for the whole app , **or even make MaterialDesign Default styles override my custom styles when MaterialDesign is loaded.**

Comment: I would make two dictionaries with default styles for all the necessary elements. And at runtime, when changing isMaterialDesign in App resources, it would replace these dictionaries with each other.

Comment: Sorry i didn't fully understand , will i make 2 dictionaries  with the same style names but different styles , then switch between them?  what i tried is to test if MaterialDesign default theme would be applied automatically on this button  
         <Button  Content="Button 1" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" MaxWidth="60" MaxHeight="30" />              after i unloaded the Dictionary containing CustomButtonStyle , but i got an error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change themes in runtime, you need to make dynamic styles, instead of statics.

So instead of `{StaticResource SomeStyle}`, it would be -> `{DynamicResource SomeStyle}`.
Then, you need to have the same name styles for both themes (material design and yours), because the button would have this dynamic style and it will change any time you want (with button, or other control), it will try to search for the same name style on the new theme provided.

It should change as desired, I have already done this, by following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHbQs99o4IA&t=1269s&ab_channel=TacticDevs), I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> i didn't fully understand , will i make 2 dictionaries

Simple example.

First dictionary `/SO/OthmaneOuazzani/Question78176707/MDStyles.xaml`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesign2.Defaults.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Second dictionary `/SO/OthmaneOuazzani/Question78176707/MyStyles.xaml`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Class `SwitchResources` for switching dictionaries:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace Core2024.SO.OthmaneOuazzani.Question78176707
{
    public class SwitchResources : ResourceDictionary
    {
        private Uri? first;
        private Uri? second;
        private bool isFirst;

        public Uri? First
        {
            get => first;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(first, value))
                    return;
                first = value;
                if (!IsFirst)
                    return;
                if (value is not null)
                    Source = value;
            }
        }
        public Uri? Second
        {
            get => second;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(second, value))
                    return;
                second = value;
                if (IsFirst)
                    return;
                if (value is not null)
                    Source = value;
            }
        }

        public bool IsFirst
        {
            get => isFirst;
            set
            {
                if (isFirst == value)
                    return;
                isFirst = value;
                if (IsFirst)
                {
                    if (First is not null)
                        Source = First;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Second is not null)
                        Source = Second;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SetIsFirst(bool isFirst)
        {
            SwitchResources? switchResources = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.OfType<SwitchResources>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (switchResources is not null)
            {
                switchResources.IsFirst = isFirst;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App:

```xml
<Application x:Class="Core2024.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:question78176707="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.OthmaneOuazzani.Question78176707"
             StartupUri="/SO/OthmaneOuazzani/Question78176707/TestSwitchResourcesWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <question78176707:SwitchResources
                    First="/SO/OthmaneOuazzani/Question78176707/MDStyles.xaml"
                    Second="/SO/OthmaneOuazzani/Question78176707/MyStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Test:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.OthmaneOuazzani.Question78176707.TestSwitchResourcesWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.OthmaneOuazzani.Question78176707"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestSwitchResourcesWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <UniformGrid>
        <Button Content="MD Styles" Click="OnMd"/>
        <Button Content="My Styles" Click="OnMy"/>
    </UniformGrid>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
        private void OnMd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SwitchResources.SetIsFirst(true);
        }

        private void OnMy(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SwitchResources.SetIsFirst(false);
        }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what i did. It worked perfectly.